# Outputting sorted sections of sorted data to a variable?

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell code:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content uccxResourceList_forReference.xml
$xml.resources.resource |
    Select-Object firstname, lastname, extension,
        @{Name="Team"; Expression={($_.team.name)}} | 
    Sort Team |
    Format-Table
```

which produces a table like this:

```
firstName   lastName    extension   Team
---------   --------    ---------   ----------------
Homer       Simpson     1000        SafetyInspectors
Frank       Grimes      1001        SafetyInspectors
Lenford     Leonard     1002        SafetyInspectors
Carlton     Carlson     1003        SafetyInspectors
Montgomery  Burns       2000        Executives
Waylon      Smithers    2001        Executives
```

What I would like to do is output each team into its own file.  So not just a simple `| Out-File teamlist.txt` at the end, but I would like to output a text file containing all of the "SafetyInspectors" and another with all of the "Executives".

I know I could get this done with a subsequent `foreach` loop but I feel it could also be done in the pipeline and I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: take a look at the `Group-Object` cmdlet - it will let you group your objects by any property [or calculated property]. then you can write out the items in each group to the desired file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to output to a csv file (which easily is imported again) , so:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content uccxResourceList_forReference.xml
$xml.resources.resource |
    Select-Object firstname, lastname, extension,
        @{Name="Team"; Expression={($_.team.name)}} | 
      Group-Object Team | ForEach-Object {
         $_.Group | Export-Csv ("{0}.csv" -f $_.Name) -NoTypeInformation
      }
```

Should return something like this:

```
> gc .\Executives.csv
"firstName","lastName","extension","Team"
"Montgomery","Burns","2000","Executives"
"Waylon","Smithers","2001","Executives"

> gc .\SafetyInspectors.csv
"firstName","lastName","extension","Team"
"Homer","Simpson","1000","SafetyInspectors"
"Frank","Grimes","1001","SafetyInspectors"
"Lenford","Leonard","1002","SafetyInspectors"
"Carlton","Carlson","1003","SafetyInspectors"
```

Comment: Perfect!  That is EXACTLY what I was after.  I didn't want to complicate the post with exporting to CSV since I already had a good handle on that part, but the `Group-Object Team | ForEach-Object { $_.Group |...` portion is what I was having trouble with.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for feedback, if you take a look at the output of `Group-Object` you'll see the properties `Count,Name,Group` you'll have to unwrap again - or - export directly to a file with the name property (here the Team).